# how to set get_magic_quotes_gpc to Off

Tags: php

How can I set get_magic_quotes_gpc to Off in php.ini ? 
I have tried to overwrite value to Off in php.ini. it is showing Off in file but when i echo, it returns 1 means On.

any suggesion that can help me..

I am using XAMPP server ...

Comment: you want probably to change magic_quotes_gpc

Comment: Out of interest sake, as of PHP 5.4.4 this has reached EOL and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 4):

```
ini_set("magic_quotes_gpc", "Off");
```

it will only work for old versions of PHP.  Newer versions of PHP will not allow you to change the setting

Comment: Do I need to restart my server?

Comment: if you write this code in .php then you don't need restart server. If you write it in php.ini then you neet to restart

Comment: They took that feature out in php 4.2.3 I believe.  You have to set it via the ini file

Comment: @Foo: [I belive they didn't](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) they would have info about deletion

Comment: @genesis If you read that page(http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), there is a reference to the options list (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).  and it clearly says that magic_quotes_gpc was changed from PHP_INI_ALL to PHP_INI_PERDIR, which means (http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) "Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf"

Comment: @genesis: helps to read the page.  The sentence "Not all the available options can be changed using ini_set(). There is a list of all available options in the appendix." had the link on the word appendix

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the apache server?  You have to restart the server to force php.ini to be reprocessed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this portable code

```
    <?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        unset($process[$key][$k]);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
            $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
        } else {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }
}
unset($process);
  }
 ?>
```

If access to the server configuration is unavailable, use of .htaccess is also an option

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php